# Problem Libertine semi-bold with lining nums

Tags: bold, libertine, oldstylenums, liningnums

I wish I could use the semi-bold version of the Libertine font.

By default, I use elzevirian numbers and there, no problem, I can have elzevirian numbers in semi-bold.

On some occasions, I would need to use lining nums with semi-bold.

However, the lining numbers that are supposed to be in semi-bold are actually in normal weight.

[image]

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[oldstyle,proportional]{libertine}
\DeclareRobustCommand\textsb[1]{{\libertineSB#1}}

\begin{document}
\LARGE

\noindent
Some "default" text with old style nums : 1234567890\\
\textsb{Some semi-bold text with old style nums : 1234567890}\\
\textbf{Some bold text with old style nums : 1234567890}\\

\noindent
Some text with lining nums : \liningnums{1234567890}\\
\textsb{Some semi-bold text with lining nums : \liningnums{1234567890}}\\
\textbf{Some bold text with lining nums : \liningnums{1234567890}}\\
\end{document}
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. I get semibold figures. Can you please add `\listfiles` to the top of the example, run LaTeX and report what you find at the end of the log file?

Comment: @egreg not with lualatex, only with pdflatex.

Comment: @egreg I tried with PDFLaTeX and... its works. I have no problem anymore. Idem with if I use Lualatex or Xetex. It's weird... Normally, I use the TeXMaker with "Quick Run". Sorry for the inconvenience, I didn't know "Quick run" could cause this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with `pdflatex`, but not with (Lua|Xe)LaTeX, due to a bug in `libertine.sty` that resets the font family, instead of adding the required features when doing `\liningnums`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\usepackage[oldstyle,proportional]{libertine}

\DeclareTextFontCommand\textsb{\libertineSB}

\iftutex % XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\liningnums}{m}{%
    {\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}#1}%
  }
\fi

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some "default" text with old style nums: 1234567890\\
\textsb{Some semi-bold text with old style nums: 1234567890}\\
\textbf{Some bold text with old style nums: 1234567890}

\noindent
Some text with lining nums: \liningnums{1234567890}\\
\textsb{Some semi-bold text with lining nums: \liningnums{1234567890}}\\
\textbf{Some bold text with lining nums: \liningnums{1234567890}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right! It works! Thank you very much! ;)

Comment: Version 5.3.0 of `libertine`, released 2020-03-26, should have fixed the issue.